# How to make a material a texture for use in other 3d applications

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, file-format

I have an asset I am selling, and I am using a material that has shaders only Blender has. Is there a way to make the material act as a texture so it can work in other 3D software like 3DS Max and Maya? if it helps, i have the node setup:

[image]

I think it has something to do with baking, which I have no idea what it is or how to use it. Oh, forgot to add, it is a procedural leather texture. Is it possible for a material that has no textures to be exported and used in a different software? Would be very helpful.

Comment: have you tried using the search box at the top of the page?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=export+cycles+material or https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=bake+cycles+material

Comment: what does baking do? can i save the material as a separate file?

Comment: Procedural textures differ depending on the software. They are not standardized AFAIK. (OSL is, but that's another story.) You will need to bake the procedural textures.